# AngJS - Get the injected dependencies list

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-injector

Just suppose I created a service like this:

```
.service('foo', ['bar', function(bar){
//var deplist = *something*

for(..){
     deplist[..].method();
}
}]);
```

Is there any way to retrieve a list of name (and, obviuosly, objects) of injected dependecies from inside the service? 
I need this because I've a lot of dependencies each one of theme must does the same thing, so I'd like to put theme in a cycle

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies are available in `arguments` object.

Try

```
var deplist = arguments;
```

Comment: `arguments` is not an array.

Comment: Sorry, I've not correctly explained the issue: I need to get also the name of the dependency, not only its properties

Answer (score 0):

You could specify your function and the dependencies distinct and access the dependency list.

```
function your_service(dep1, dep2)
{
    console.log(your_service.$inject);
}
your_service.$inject = ['dep1', 'dep2'];

...

app.service('service', your_service);
```